# Exclude age, gender and region from firebase Analytics on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Recently I had a specific request, don't allow firebase analytics to collect user's data like gender, age and region (Due to GDPR). I know, we can completely disable Analytics.

Firebase Analytics says:

> Analytics automatically logs some user properties; you don't need to add any code to enable them. If you need to collect additional data, you can set up to 25 different Analytics User Properties per project. Note that user property names are case-sensitive and that setting two user properties whose names differ only in case results in two distinct user properties being logged.

You can't use a small set of user property names reserved by Google:

- **Age**
- **Gender**
- **Interest**

I was wondering if there is a way to only disable these users properties which are logged automatically??

Thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: Be more specific about your question and show some code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to exclude any of the [automatic properties](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486) (except, apparently, on iOS, where you have to do some configuration to enable them).  The only configurations are documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection). If you're required not to collect that information about the end user, your only option is to disable Analytics altogether.

Note the the data is fully anonymized.  There is no way to track the properties back to a specific end user, unless you add some personally identifying information to a user record, such as a user ID.